# Calculating torus surface area

Tags: integration, area

I was trying to calculate the surface area of a torus, whose tube radius is r, and distance from "singularity" to the center of the torus tube is R.

[Here's what I've tried to do](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6orrSqDLLNOVGJfbUtCZlZnT1E/view?pli=1) (The reason I think I'm wrong is because of [wolfram alpha torus page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=torus)).

I should note that the same methode did yield the right volume.

Comment: See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem

Answer (score 4):

Use the fact that the torus is a surface of revolution.  Consider a torus generated by the rotation of the circle $$(x-R)^2 + y^2 = r^2, \quad R > r > 0$$ about the $y$-axis.  Then by symmetry, consider the top half given by $$f(x) = (r^2 - (x-R)^2)^{1/2}, \quad R-r \le x \le R+r.$$  Then in the interval $$x \in [x_0, x_0 + \Delta x],$$ the differential arc length of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ is $$\Delta s \approx \sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0))^2} = \Delta x \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)}{\Delta x}\right)^2},$$ and as $\Delta x \to 0$, we see that the squared term is a derivative; hence $$ds = \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} \, dx$$ at each point of integration along the $x$-axis.  This formula should be quite familiar.  Then the differential surface area of this differential arc length as rotated about the $y$-axis is given by $$dA = 2 \pi x \, ds = 2\pi x \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} \, dx.$$  Consequently, for half of the torus (the half above the $x$-axis), we find $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}(r^2 - (x-R)^2)^{-1/2} \cdot 2(R-x) = \frac{R-x}{f(x)},$$ and $$\sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} = \frac{r}{f(x)};$$ hence the total surface area is $$A = 2\pi r \int_{x=R-r}^{R+r} \frac{x}{f(x)} \, dx.$$  To make the calculation easier, we consider the substitution $$u = \frac{x-R}{r}, \quad dx = r \, du,$$ resulting in $$A = 2 \pi r \int_{u=-1}^1 \frac{ru \, du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} + \frac{R \, du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}.$$  The first term is clearly $0$, being the integral of an odd function over $[-1,1]$, leaving the second term:  $$A = 2\pi Rr \int_{u=-1}^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} = 2\pi^2 Rr,$$ after a standard transformation $u = \sin \theta$.  Therefore, the total surface area of the torus is $2A = 4\pi^2 Rr$.

Answer (score 1):

**Geometrical Approach**: There is a simpler & easier approach to find the surface area of a torus having radius of tube $r$ & distance $R$ from singularity to the center of torus.

Assuming torus to be a circular cylinder having radius $r$ & the length $L=2\pi R$, the surface area of the torus is $$=(\text{circumference of tube})\times \text{(mean length of tube)}$$  $$=(2\pi r)\times(2\pi R)$$ $$=\color{red}{4\pi^2 Rr}$$

Comment: Is it obvious that this should work? (In other words, is Pappus' centroid theorem obvious?)