# The Skimpy Donut

Tags: calculus, volume, surface-integrals, maple

I've come across this problem on several calculus tutorials but can't find any solutions for it.  Can someone please explain how to figure these questions out?

### [Link to "The Skimpy Donut" problem](http://people.math.sc.edu/calclab/142L-S11/labs/SkimpyDonut.pdf)

---

For question #1 I found the link below that helped me figure it out:

[Volume of a Torus: the Washer Method](http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter17/section03.html)

`ANSWER for question #1:`

[image]

---

But I can't find any help on how to solve problems 2, 3, and 4 based on the instructions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the formulae $V= 2\pi^2ab^2,$ $A = 4\pi^2 ab$ are known. Then, as noticed by others, $A = (2V)/b .$ Thus if we assume $V$ is fixed at some $V_0,$ we are trying to minimize $(2V_0)/b.$ That is the same as maximizing $b$ given the constraints of the situation.

One of the constraints is $0\le b\le a.$ The other one is

$$\tag 1 b= \left ( \frac{V_0}{2\pi^2a}\right)^{1/2}.$$

Looking at the $a$-$b$ plane, we want to consider the intersection in the first quadrant of the curve $b = V_0/(2\pi^2a)^{1/2}$ with the region $0\le b\le a.$ The intersection point with the largest $b$ occurs where the curve intesects the line $b=a.$ Thus we only need solve $V_0 = 2\pi^2a^3,$ which gives $a=b= (V_0/(2\pi^2))^{1/3}$ as yielding the minimum surface area.

If we take $b$ tiny and $a$ large so as to have $V_0= 2\pi^2ab^2,$ it is clear that $A = (2V_0)/b$ can be made arbitrarily large. Thus there is no maximum surface area for a fixed volume.

As for the surface area formula $A = 4\pi^2 ab,$ we can obtain this by noticing the upper half of the torus is the solid swept out by revolving the upper half of the circle $(x-a)^2 + y^2= b^2$ $360$ degrees about the $y$-axis. Solving for $y$ in the upper half circle gives

$$y = \sqrt { b^2 - (x-a)^2}.$$

The desired surface area is thus

$$2\cdot 2\pi \int_{a-b}^{a+b}x\cdot \sqrt {1+ (dy/dx)^2}\, dx.$$

This works out nicely. Ask if you have questions on it.

Comment: can you please show me the Integral filled out and answer? Here is what I tried doing, but it's giving me an answer greater than the original SA of 592, so I think I'm doing something wrong.  https://imgur.com/a/IPyzM

Comment: @mdo123 In the integral you link to, that should be $\sqrt {1 +(dy/dx)^2},$ not $\sqrt {1+y^2}.$

Answer (score 0):

I will let you solve for the volume and surface area any way you choose. Here I'll just give the results using Pappus's centroid theorems. The solutions are

$$
V=2\pi R A=2\pi^2 Rr^2\\
S=2\pi R C=4\pi^2 Rr
$$

where $R$ is the centroid of the revolving circle, and $A=\pi r^2$ and $C=2\pi r$ are its area and circumference, respectively. Here, $R$ and $r$ correspond to $a$ and $b$ in the problem.

Then we find that we can express

$$S=\frac{2V}{r}$$

If $V$ is fixed, then the maximum surface area coincides with smallest radius. In this problem, the smallest radius is equal to $R$, i.e., the doughnut with no hole has the largest surface area. As the hole increases in size (for a fixed volume) the surface area necessarily decreases.

Comment: Isn't it the other away around (minimum SA is with no hole and max is infinite)? I ran a test on https://www.aqua-calc.com/calculate/volume-torus.  I made a = 4 (instead of 5, to simulate making the hole smaller and I made b = 3.343 (in order to get the same volume as when a = 3, approx 882).  When I did this the surface area decreased to 527.

Comment: I can't argue with your calculations. When I recast the problem in the form $r=aR,\quad a\le1$ and I plot $S$ vs. $a$, I find that $S$ increases monotonically from $r=R$ as volume is held constant. Yet I can't see what's wrong with the equations I wrote.

Comment: Your answer is fine until the last two sentences. It is the **largest** radius that is equal to $R$, not the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

**Item 2**

The derivation of the surface area formula actually exists already on this site, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436376/calculating-torus-surface-area). You can also see it done in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMVwXglUp60) YouTube video.

**Item 3**

We want to find the minimum surface area for the fixed volume of $90 \pi^2$. We know that the volume $V$ and the surface area $S$ is given by the formulas
$$V=2 \pi^2 a b^2 = 90 \pi^2 \tag {1}$$

$$S = 4 \pi^2 ab \tag {2}$$
From (1) we can find $$a = \frac {45}{b^2} \tag {3}$$
Inserting this in (2) gives $$S=\frac {180 \pi^2}{b} \tag{4}$$
We want $S$ as small as possible so $b$ must be as large as possible. But for a torus $b \le a$, otherwise it overlaps itself. So $b = a$, which using (3) gives $a = b = \sqrt[3]{45}$, and the minimum surface area is then $$S_{min} = 4 \pi^2 45^{\frac 2 3 } \approx 50.6 \pi^2$$

**Item 4**

Equation (4) shows there is no maximum surface area as $S \to \infty$ as $b \to 0$.